# Performing Multiple Queries in MySQL Event

Tags: mysql

I am trying to alter my event in MySQL. I want it to perform the first INSERT then delete all the data from a table. When I try to alter the event with this code:

```
ALTER event transfer_to_population_hist do INSERT INTO population_hist
            (
                        location_id,
                        count,
                        dtm
            )
SELECT DISTINCT(location_id),
                Max(count),
                dtm
FROM            current_population
GROUP BY        current_population.location_id;DELETE
FROM   current_population;
```

it performs 2 queries.  One where it alters the event only including the insert statement and then another query where it deletes all the data from the table.

I want it to also delete the data during the event.

Comment: Thx, for the edit I suppose. Formatting is to each his own, but this has not resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the solution I was looking for, but an easy way to accomplish the task is to just put the queries into a stored procedure and call the stored procedure in the event.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple statements if you surround them within BEGIN and END.

Comment: That is what I thought, and I tried that, but it did not work in the event.